# How to get old code from replaced procedure (PL/SQL)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure which was working until I mistakenly replaced by other code.
So my procedure started with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xxx.yyy`, and I mistakenly replaced with some simple code and saved it.

Since I had replaced in my procedure so it got replaced but now it doesn't work the way I want any more. How can I get my old code that was in that procedure (before replaced)?

Comment: Backup or get code from version control(Git/SVN) if you have any.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz, I dont have any but it was under my schema wondering if there are other way??

Comment: Well I guess you don't have any DDL auditing enabled or system-level trigger to  catch DDL changes. I propose to search for backup or try to check this on different environment like QA/DEV/...

Comment: So the teaching is: use source control for your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you're connected at `xxx` schema, try to use :

```
select s.text 
  from user_source 
  as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day s
 where s.name = 'YYY';
```

*to get your procedure's source. It gives your the data of one day before. You may convert `'1' day` to `'10' hour`, `'150' minute` .. etc. depending on your need, in the case your `db_flashback_retention_target` database parameter has been set as large as enough.*

Answer (score 0):

If there are archive logs for the search period. You can use the utility LogMiner.
for example:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY acs_ss2.rest_of_day is

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    procedure starting(p_date date) is
      rec_newrest   r_rest%rowtype;
      rec_oldrest   r_rest%rowtype;
      rec_rest      r_rest%rowtype;
      v_station   integer := 8902;
      v_dt1 date;
      v_dt2 date;
    begin
SQL CODE...
```

Determine the desired log files by the time of the incident.

```
select name, first_time,  next_time
  from v$archived_log
where first_time >sysdate -3/24

/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47429_769799469.dbf  22-ноя-2018 10:56:12    22-ноя-2018 12:13:48
/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47430_769799469.dbf  22-ноя-2018 12:13:48    22-ноя-2018 13:17:06
/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47431_769799469.dbf  22-ноя-2018 13:17:06    22-ноя-2018 13:39:38
```

Run the logminer utility.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47429_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.NEW); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47430_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_47431_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 

EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);
```

Run SQL for restore our CODE, see  column sql_undo.

```
SELECT 
to_char(timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
operation,  
sql_redo,
sql_undo
 FROM v$logmnr_contents
where 
seg_owner='SYS' and  
seg_name='SOURCE$'
==>
TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')       OPERATION                              SQL_REDO                                                                                             SQL_UNDO                                                                                             
----------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
22-11-2018 13:39:14                             DELETE                                 delete from "SYS"."SOURCE$" where "OBJ#" = '197353' and "LINE" = '1' and "SOURCE" = 'package body re insert into "SYS"."SOURCE$"("OBJ#","LINE","SOURCE") values ('197353','1','package body rest_of_day i 
22-11-2018 13:39:14                             DELETE                                 delete from "SYS"."SOURCE$" where "OBJ#" = '197353' and "LINE" = '2' and "SOURCE" = '
' and ROWID =  insert into "SYS"."SOURCE$"("OBJ#","LINE","SOURCE") values ('197353','2','
');                       
22-11-2018 13:39:14                             DELETE                                 delete from "SYS"."SOURCE$" where "OBJ#" = '197353' and "LINE" = '3' and "SOURCE" = '/*------------- insert into "SYS"."SOURCE$"("OBJ#","LINE","SOURCE") values ('197353','3','/*------------------------ 
22-11-2018 13:39:14                             DELETE                                 delete from "SYS"."SOURCE$" where "OBJ#" = '197353' and "LINE" = '4' and "SOURCE" = 'procedure start insert into "SYS"."SOURCE$"("OBJ#","LINE","SOURCE") values ('197353','4','procedure starting(p_date  
22-11-2018 13:39:14                             DELETE                                 delete from "SYS"."SOURCE$" where "OBJ#" = '197353' and "LINE" = '5' and "SOURCE" = '  rec_newrest r insert into "SYS"."SOURCE$"("OBJ#","LINE","SOURCE") values ('197353','5','  rec_newrest r_rest%rowty
```